# How can I get the value from one function into document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 files. File one calls a function in file 2. I can alert the value passed into file 2 if that function is outside of the document ready function. I need that value inside of document ready. Is there a way to do this?

file 1:

```
setId(1);
```

file 2

```
function setId(v){
  alert(v); // This works
}
```

If I place the function within the document ready function, I can no longer access the value passed in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code define setId function

```
window.setId = function(v){
alert(v);
}
```

EDIT:
Method 2 from Nick

```
window.myapp = window.myapp || {};

myapp.setId = function(v){
alert(v);
}
```

to call the setId function

```
myapp.setId("test");
```

Comment: Thank you Bharath! I'll credit you for this answer when the timer expires

Comment: I would highly recommend that you do not just pollute the global like that.  At the very least do something like this inside of each files' document.ready

window.app = window.app || {};
window.app.setId = function() {...}

That way you are jailing your things and also can build up a common app global from your various files without needing to redefine everything in each file.

Comment: Yes that is standard way to use this in bigger applications. @NickSharp: thanks

Comment: Nick, to be honest with you, I am not very javascript/jquery savvy at all. polluting the global space doesn't mean anything to me. I'm happy to take your suggestion if you would be so kind as to maybe provide an example of how this should be done.

Comment: @user1709311 - Bharath put a great example up in his answer.  But essentially everything that you just put on window. self. global. this. etc is usually put on the main global "scope".  This can lead to crazy bugs when different scripts are both putting something on the window.foo object.  So to avoid this you can do just what Bharath put in and make a window.myApp = window.myApp || {}; and then always just put your stuff there